# Excel - We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking insert function on the formula tabs

Tags: excel, office365, offset

When I use the data validation tab to insert a list of data as a drop-down list control, I receive the following error.

In the source tab I copy pasted the following formula which is working fine when I tested on a cell, but when I paste the same formula into the Source textbox of Data validation the error message pops up.

[image]

**The formula:**

```
=OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Stage]], MATCH(Invoice_Plan!$D$6,Table1[Project],0),0,COUNTIF(Table1[Project],Invoice_Plan!$D$6),1)
```

When I press the F9 button to view the result, it displays the list of *values as:*

```
={"Mobilization Advance";"Concept Design ";"Schematic Design";"Detailed Design";"Tender Documents"}
```

However, I'm not sure why the same formula doesn't work as a source in Data Validation tab. would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Show some of your data so that we can check and give you solution?

Answer (score 1):

The validation object accepts a list of values or a named range containing a list of values. It doesn't accept a formula dynamically defining a range.

To work around the problem you might create a dynamic named range and use the range's name as a reference for the validation. I created a named range called "ValidationList" using the formula below to define it.

```
=OFFSET(Formulas!$A$7,0,0,10-COUNTBLANK(Formulas!$A$7:$A$16))
```

Note that Formulas!A7:A16 actually is the address of the named range itself but larger. The effect of this formula is to make the list as long as there are values in the column starting from A7 down. In my example, the list is limited to 10 values max. You could make it 50 or 100 - any number. The important thing is that the number (here it is "10") in `10-COUNTBLANK(Formulas!$A$7:$A$16)` is equal to the number of cells in the specified range (here A7:A16, meaning 10 cells). Of course, the worksheet's name (here it is 'Formulas') should be a sheet existing in your workbook.

To fill values into the 'ValidationList' range you might use a formula like `=IFERROR(IF(Len(Invoice_Plan!$D$6)),Invoice_Plan!$D$6,""),"")`. Note that you can't use the even simple =Invoice_Plan!$D$6 because the formula defining the 'ValidationList' range needs blank cells to contain a null string to avoid including them in the list of the validation drop-down.

Now you can set the Source in data validation simply to `=ValidationList`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment. By any chance can you share an example here, I've no idea how to work on your solution.

Comment: I expanded my above answer to include details of the proposed solution.